# Setting immutable variables using clones

Tags: solidity, blockchain, openzeppelin, factory, clone

I've created a factory where I can clone my smart contracts using the [openzeppelin clones factory](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol). The problem I'm facing is that my "child" or "initializable" contract needs to update variables on a new contract. This requires my variables to be mutable, which isn't gas efficient, and makes my system feel less secure. How can I create immutable variables with a cloning factory?

Child/Initializable contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract Raffle is Initializable {
    uint256 public ticketPrice;
    address public raffleAdmin;
    address public raffleOwner;

    function initialize(uint256 _ticketPrice, address _raffleOwner) public payable initializer {
        ticketPrice = _ticketPrice;
        raffleAdmin = msg.sender;
        raffleOwner = _raffleOwner;
    }
}
```

Factory contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract RaffleProxyFactory is Ownable {
    address public implementationContract;

    address[] public allClones;

    event NewClone(address _clone);

    constructor(address _implementation) {
        implementationContract = _implementation;
    }

    function createNewRaffle(uint256 _ticketPrice) payable external returns(address instance) {
        instance = Clones.clone(implementationContract);
        (bool success, ) = instance.call{value: msg.value} (abi.encodeWithSignature("initialize(uint256,address)", _ticketPrice, msg.sender));
        allClones.push(instance);
        emit NewClone(instance);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also think it's not possible because these constants are imprinted into bytecode that got cloned. You have to secure that `initialize` function and make sure it's only called once. I saw people usually use `_disableInitializers();` for that

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you can not, immutable variables can only be set during the constructor and in clones/upgradeable contracts there is no constructor call.